# How to launch specific test in emulator

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, flutter-test

I wonder how to launch specific test in android emulator. Suppose I have some tests in file with path `test/my_test_path/file.dart`:

```
void main() {
  group('group test', () {

    testWidgets('test1', (tester) async {
      ...
    });

    testWidgets('fancy name test 2', (tester) async {
      ...
    });
}
```

and If I run command: `flutter run test/my_test_path/file.dart` in the terminal, tests are launching in emulator one by one. I want to run only specific test by this way, for example test named 'fancy name test 2'. How can I do that?

Answer (score -1):

```
flutter test --plain-name "name of your test"
```

Comment: It works but I want to launch test in emulator (simulate test), I can do this by command `flutter run ...` but it launches every tests in file. Your command only run test (doesn't launch it on emulator).

Comment: I want to get something similar like in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TiCA0CEePyE&list=PLjxrf2q8roU3ahJVrSgAnPjzkpGmL9Czl&index=69 at 12:05 but my file has many tests and they run one by one. I just want launch only one from file.

Comment: But it should run only the test you name? Like for example if you write flutter test --plain-name "test1" only test1 runs. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: I only want to run one widget test, but it should run in the emulator, because I want to observe live what the tester clicks and tests in the UI.